# How we can create folder/subfolder/bucket at Amazon Glacier?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

Can I create buckets or folder as on S3? And how to upload/download from it?

P.S. Using c#

Answer (score 0):

You can create different "vaults", each of which contains a set of archives (files). You must download an API implementation from somewhere such as GitHub, or program your own.